# How to redirect different sub domain requests to different port

Tags: apache

I have two applications, one is the `www.myexample.com`, another is the `blog.myexample.com`. I am using PHP and Apache.

Now, I want to let `www.myexample.com` runs on port 82 of my machine, and `blog.myexample.com` on port 83, on the same machine. How to configure the apache and/ or the PHP scripts so that when the requests for the requests are served properly?

**Edit: Thanks for everyone who responds, but I afraid I don't get the question clear-- my bad!**

**What I really want is to simulate a condition whereby the www.myexample.com and blog.myexample.com are located on different machines. So when a request comes in, the gateway server ( the one which is also hosting www.myexample.com) will check whether this is a request for www.myexample.com or for blog.myexample.com and does the necessary reroutes.**

How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Ummmm... WHY? Are you aware of name-based virtual hosting?

Comment: Seconded @derobert's "why". Please explain.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for didn't post a good question in the first place

Comment: when you say reroute to blog, do you mean redirect to blog.example.com (blog.example.com appears in the address bar)?  If so then you don't need a reverse proxy, just create the DNS entry for www.example.com to point to the first machine and blog.example.com to the second machine

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I will assume that you have your own reason for wanting the two sites (`www` and `blog`) to run on different ports - and in different processes.  If this is not what you intended, e.g. you did not want to have two distinct processes, then having different ports may not be what you intended either: use `VirtualHost` instead, to co-host the two domains within the same apache+php instance on port 80.  *Otherwise, read on.*

Assuming that you have your two apache+php processes listening on localhost:82 and localhost:83 respectively, bring up a third, apache-only process to act as a reverse proxy.  Have the reverse proxy apache instance listen for requests coming on port 80 from the internet, with two virtual host definitions.  The first virtual host definition, `www`, would forward requests to localhost:82, whereas the second virtual host definition, `blog`, would forward requests to locahost:83, e.g.:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# www
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.myexample.com
  ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:82/
  ProxyPassReverse        /       http://localhost:82/
</VirtualHost>

# blog
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.myexample.com
  ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:83/
  ProxyPassReverse        /       http://localhost:83/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: FYI, this is great for development work with multiple sites. I use Visual Studio, and it is set up to work with the built-in server, which requires port numbers. If you set up your projects to use static ports, you can then install apache and use this configuration to point a domain to those ports, shove the domains into your hosts file, and voila, named sites that all point to different ports on your local machine, but have readable names. Very handy.

Comment: On windows, I also had to enable mod_proxy_http before this would work.

Comment: linux use `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`

And be aware of the security warning regarding forward proxies on the Apache site http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#access

Answer (score 5):

I use proxy for this type of things.

In my example, I have apache 1.3 running on port 80, but I needed svn repository to run on apache 2.2, and I didn't want to type :82 on the end of the domain every time. So I made proxy redirection on apache 1.3 (port 80):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName svn.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias svn
  ServerAdmin my@email.com

  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass / http://svn:82/
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the following line on terminal (specify your domain and sub domain name correctly)

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.domain.com.conf
```

Paste the following code and change as your requirement

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com
        ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com
        ProxyRequests Off

        #ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        <Location />
                ProxyPreserveHost On
                ProxyPass http://domain.com:8080/
                ProxyPassReverse http://domain.com:8080/
        </Location>
     # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
     #SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Run the following lines on terminal (specify your domain and sub domain name correctly)

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod subdomain.domain.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I  guess "sudo a2enmod subdomain.domain.com.conf" should be "sudo a2ensite subdomain.domain.com.conf"  here, as we need to enable site subdomain.domain.com.conf (not a module).

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my hat:

```
Listen 82
Listen 83
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4 # Use your server's IP here

<VirtualHost www.myexample.com:82>
# Configure www.myexample.com here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost blog.myexample.com:83>
# Configure blog.myexample.com here
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complete answer to this would be to do something like this which allow you to setup a proxy gateway which is what is loosly described above.

ServerName localhost

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from localhost
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests           Off
ProxyPreserveHost       On      

ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:10081/
ProxyPassReverse        /       http://localhost:10081/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /    http://localhost:10081/
```