# Hosting Ghost on an Apache Subdomain

Tags: node.js, apache, ghost-blog

My server runs on apache, but [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) requires node.js to be hosted. Rest of my website runs on apache. How can I make it run on a subdomain of my website without it interfering with other applications?

Comment: You can proxy request on your subdomain from apache to node.js

Comment: @ChiragJain How do I do that? I am a newbie to web hosting, I just follow the steps in the documentation.

Comment: Read more about mod_proxy in apache

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server

Comment: eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589368/how-to-redirect-different-sub-domain-requests-to-different-port

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the url to redirect on the port of your nodejs-app:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nodeapp/(.*) http://localhost:3000/$1 [P]
```

If your app starts at port 3000, you can access it at: http://www.your-domain.com/nodeapp/...

Answer (score 0):

Use apache mod proxy.

Setup your virtual host configuration to proxypass it to the port which ghost is listening on.

Answer (score 0):

Using mod proxy will be a good choice. Here is a small template:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName your-url.com
     ServerAlias www.your-url.com
     ProxyRequests off
     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2368/
     ProxyPassReverse / http:/127.0.0.1:2368/
</VirtualHost>
```

But if you haven't use Proxy mode before, please use this command:`a2enmod proxy` before you restart your Appache service.